# Anything wrong with naming a controller/table users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called `users` and im having some routing issues. I scaffolded, and when i try to open index, i get routing errors: No route matches action `show`, `edit`, `destroy`. I did rake route and theyre all there. If i delete the show, edit, destroy, the index loads fine.

Only thing i can think of is that rails defaults to having its own users set up.

Any thoughts to why this may be? Is there any way to have a controller called users?

Comment: What are the actual classes/routes/etc?

Comment: I guess some existing route is overriding you new route, Try to place this route at top of your routes.rb to confirm this. Then you may tweak the existing route to correct the overriding route.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with having a *users* table.  If you have a *users* table, you should also have a user.rb model and users_controller.rb.  These should have been generated when you created the *users* scaffold.

To handle routing for your users_controller, config/routes.rb should include:

```
resources :users
```